# Time not saving in UTC

Tags: python, django, forms, time

I have a form with a TimeField, which takes inputs from a dynamically created dropdown. All my other forms successfully convert dates and times based on a users timezone, and save them in the database as UTC. This doesn't seem to be happening with my time input on this specific form. I believe it is because it takes a string value from a list I have, but I am not sure how to change that since the list is needed for the way my dynamically generated input list is recorded. I would appreciate any help with finding a way to still dynamically generate my time dropdown and save it in UTC.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Time</label>
    {{ form.booked_time }}
</div>
```

models.py

```
class Booked(models.Model):
    booked_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class BookedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    booked_time = forms.ChoiceField(choices=time_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'id' : 'time', 'required' : 'True'}))
 'booked_time')
```

with a time_list that goes something like this

```
('', 'Time'),
('8:00 am', '8:00 am'),
('8:15 am', '8:15 am'),
('8:30 am', '8:30 am'),
```

views.py

```
def book_lesson(request, lesson_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.time_zone:
        activate(request.user.time_zone)
    else:
        deactivate()

    lesson = Lesson.objects.get(id=lesson_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookedForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            book = form.save(commit=False)
            book.student_user = request.user
            book.teacher_user = lesson.user
            book.save()
            messages.success(request,'Lesson was successfully booked!')
            return redirect('/teacher/dashboard')

        else:
            form = BookedForm()

    form = BookedForm()
    context = {'form' : form, 'lesson' : lesson}
    return render(request, 'view/book_lesson.html', context)
```

JavaScript

```
var start = document.getElementById('start').innerHTML.split('.').join('').toLocaleLowerCase();
var end = document.getElementById('end').innerHTML.split('.').join('').toLocaleLowerCase();
var time = document.getElementById('time');

time.disabled = true;

var slotTimes = [];
document.getElementById("length").onchange = function (evt) {
    var timeDistance = evt.target.value;
    var startMoment = moment(start, "h:mm a");
    var endMoment = moment(end, "h:mm a");
    slotTimes = [];

    while (startMoment.isSameOrBefore(endMoment)) {
        slotTimes.push(startMoment.format("h:mm a"));
        startMoment = startMoment.add(timeDistance, 'minutes');
    }

    addDropdown();
    disabled();
};
function addDropdown() {
    var doc = '',
        times = slotTimes,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        doc += "<option value='" + times[i] + "'>" + times[i] + "</option>";
    }

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = doc;
    disabled();
}
```

Comment: Please don't delete questions after receiving answers to them; it isn't fair on the people who've volunteered their time and efforts to help you.

Answer (score 1):

`TimeFields` don't have timezones. From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects):

> Django only supports naive time objects and will raise an exception if you attempt to save an aware time object, as a timezone for a time with no associated date does not make sense.

As noted, it doesn't make sense for a time field to have a timezone. Times without dates are by definition calendar (aka wall clock) time, they don't pick out a specific moment in time.

In practical terms, you can't convert the time to UTC without knowing the date. That's because the conversion depends on the date (think about daylight savings time).

Comment: I was not aware of that, thanks for letting me know. Would I have to save it as a date timefield and just exclude the date from it in templates, or is there another way to make the input time aware

Comment: @Shoukran: It's not a practical issue, it just doesn't make sense to use a timezone with a `TimeField`. I've edited the question with more detail.